# How to bring background image to front when in only one Ddiv

Tags: css, html, canvas, z-index

I have a canvas with a background image with below code. How can i bring the background image to front with just css? The image should come to front of canvas.

```css
.dvContainer {  
 opacity: .7;
 z-index:-100;
}
.background {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/ITWfejd.png);
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" class="dvContainer background" width="400" height="300" 
  style="background-color: red;">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: you have changed the question altogether now :D you possibly can't bring background in front... z-index won't help here... why do you need this in the first place?

Comment: i have only one div with logic to be used in canvas only

Answer (score 0):

Do this:-

```
.dvContainer {  
     opacity: .7;
     z-index:1001;
     display:none;
    }

    .background {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/ITWfejd.png);
     background-position: center;
    }

    <div>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" class="dvContainer background" width="400" height="300" 
      style="background-color: red;">
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

And put that `Div Element` on the top of the page.

This will locate the div on top if not happening try to increase in z-index

Comment: increasing `z-index` alone won't bring a *parent* above a *child* in the *stacking context*, did you try it?

Comment: But yes one more thing i going to edit in my answer that you pointed out.

Comment: Can you please share the complete code snippet in jsbin. the image is not displaying at all with above snippet